# CoreNFC-IOS13: After connecting the iso15693 tag, iso15693Tag.isAvailable is always returning false

Tags: ios13, iso-15693, core-nfc

After connecting to `ios15693` NFC Tag, when I am checking `iso15693Tag.isAvailable`, it always returns false but I am able to get the system information details.

I am trying to connect the `ios15693` NFC-V type and trying to read the
data but I am not able get the results.

I am able to

- Detect the tag
- Connect to tag
- Get the system information (`dsfid`, `afi`, `blockSize`, `blockNumber`, `icReference`)

I am not able to 
 - Read the data from `NFC-V` type :(

```
/* Code to Start detecting the iso14443/iso15693*/

tagSession = NFCTagReaderSession(pollingOption: [.iso14443, .iso15693], delegate: self)
tagSession?.alertMessage = "Hold your iPhone near the item to learn more about it."
tagSession?.begin()

/* Call back function when iso 15693 and miFare nfc tag detected */

func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) { 
    if case let NFCTag.iso15693(iso15693Tag) = tags.first! {
        print("iso15693 out side : ========\(iso15693Tag.isAvailable)========")
        session.connect(to: tags.first!) { (error: Error?) in
             print("iso15693 in side : ========\(iso15693Tag.isAvailable)========")
    }

    if case let NFCTag.miFare(miFarTag) = tags.first! {
        print("miFarTag out side : ========\(miFarTag.isAvailable)========")
        session.connect(to: tags.first!) { (error: Error?) in
            print("miFarTag in side : ========\(miFarTag.isAvailable)========")
        }
    }
}
```

After `session.connect` the NFC tag, when we try `iso15693Tag.isAvailable`, it should return true but returns false.

Comment: There could be a possibility that, you are tapping a card with .iso14443 which is ISO7816Tag. In the pollingOptions you have mentioned two types.

Comment: @Naren Here i am checking 2 types of NFCs one is miFare and iso15693 while when i scan the miFar tag isAvailable property of the tag is false before connect and after connect it is showing true but in case of when i scan the iso15693 NFC tag before connect it returns false even after it connects its returning false.

Comment: @NarayanaDvl Any updates?